# Stopping the waiting spinner after the ajax call has finished

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on an asp.net mvc3 application and I have this jQuery function that is called when I want to remove/delete an image :

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'POST',
            context: this,
            success: function(result) {
                $(this).closest('span').remove();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
})
```

and this function is called like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePicture", new { documentImageID = image.Id }, new { @class = "delete" })
```

The problem is that at the begining of the function execution I get a very standard waiting loader that is shown on the page and it doesn't hide. I guess I have to pass something somewhere to tell it to stop, but at the first place I don't know why exactly it appears to try and think something about removing it after the method is finished. I have a feeling that this is some standard feature of asp.net mvc3 but not sure. Do I have to return something from my `DeletePicture` method (it's void now), or is there anything else standard that is done at this case or this is some custom situation and I have to explore it myself?

Comment: In your success function, you use $(this).closest('span').remove();. The "this" in this case is for the function, not the document. Use something else in your selector, like $("body").

Comment: Ok, this is done, but the loader remains.

Comment: Maybe try to add the loader span an id, and then remove it via $("#loader-id").hide(); or $("#loader-id").remove();

Comment: I'm not calling it at the first place, it's part from the asp.net mvc3.It seem that when I use Ajax I get this loader but don't know how to hide/remove it.

Comment: It seems it's standard part from the jquery that comes with mvc. One can access it through `$("#ajaxBusy")`. Kamiil T, if you want post it as answer and I'll accept it.